# How to enable dragging of map in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using leaflet.js to visualize the map. I updating the markers on the map using the following code

```
map.dragging.enable();
data.forEach(function(d)
        {
    lat=d.lat;
    lon=d.lon;
    road=d.road;
    detector=d.detector;
    markers.push((new L.circle([lat, lon], 200, {
        color: 'yellow',
        fillColor: '#f0f',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    })).bindPopup("Road Name:"+road+"<br>Detector ID: "+detector))

        });
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    map.addLayer(markers[i]);
}
map.setView([lat, lon],13);
map.dragging.enable();
```

I am enabling the dragging of the map both before and after the loop. But the map is still not draggable after the update operation. But initially when i have not updated the map markers its draggable. But when the marker locations are updated it becomes non draggable. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Could you supply a testcase on JSfiddle or preferrably [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) which reproduces your problem?

Comment: Didn't see any code to disable the map dragging, could you post more code here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to show us where you are declaring lat, lon? Is it outside of scope? You could be calling a `setView` with invalid parameters which might cause Leaflet to throw an error.